# Hartogs Operation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I know that this question has already appeared, but I would like to share my attempt to solve it as well.

Let H be the formula operation of Hartogs . Prove that  **∀A(A < A + H(A))**.

Proof:
With  **H(A)** we denote the smallest ordinal α, such that **H(A)=μα[¬α≤A]**.
So I will use that if **A** is isomorphic (0) to some ordinal **β**, then **β<α<μα**.
Hence **H(A)+A** is equivalent to **β+μα>β**.
However, (0) I think that only holds if A is well ordered.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably the context is without the axiom of choice, otherwise you'd only be asked to prove that $A<H(A)$. So you definitely cannot use the assumption that $A$ can be well-ordered.

The concept of Hartogs numbers is usually studied in the context of cardinals, so $<$ here means that there is an injection (but that part should be *really* obvious), but there is no bijection. This requires you to simply observe the defining property of $H(A)$.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila By def:H(A) us the smallest ordinal such that there is no injection betweeen H(A) and A.
But H(A)+A is this smallest ordinal plus the set itself and then there is such a function f:H(A)+A↦A which is an injection.But then it means that H(A)+A>A. Is this okay?